# Visual Studio intellisense commits after pressing a special character - python

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Intellisense in python is turning out to be more of a burden than a helpful tool.  Whenever I used it for C++, pressing '.' would pop up a list of options.  However pressing '.' while using Python commits to the intellisense option.  This also happens when pressing '(' or '{' or several other special characters.  I was under the impression that pressing 'tab' or 'enter' were the only keys that would commit to the intellisense option?

To make matters worse, Visual Studio's keyboard shortcuts don't seem to be working correctly either (or at least 1 of the main ones I use).
Pressing Ctrl + Enter would normally give me a new line above my current line however instead I get a syntax error in the School Interactive Window.

A solution to these problem would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Solutions I've tried are looking under the text editor options for python as well as the general text editor options.  I've also searched google and stack overflow but can't find a similar question

EDIT2: Changed title as well as body to reflect new found info which is that not only '.' commits to the intellisense option but all special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.  Under Tools > Options > Python > Advanced there is a "Committed by typing the following characters: {}.,:;+-*/%&|^~=<>#@\".  I thought these were characters that opened up intellisense dropdown suggestions but rather commit the intellisense option.  I just deleted all the characters and it fixed the issue.  I still haven't found the answer to my second question but since the title is named after the first issue, I'll open up a new topic for that question if I do a more thorough search and can't figure it out.